# How to use the information that is entered in Jupyter Widgets-Date picker?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

Im looking how can I use the information (in this case date) that is entered in Jupyter Widgets-Date picker.  My code below creates a widget where I can select the date.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
w=widgets.DatePicker(
    description='Pick a Date',
    disabled=False
)
w
```

[image]

How can I use the date that is selected in the widget?

Answer (score 2):

For pyspark it could be something like

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
w = widgets.DatePicker(
    description='Pick a Date',
    disabled=False
)
w
```

Then you access it like:

```
w.value
table = spark.read.parquet("path")
table.filter(F.col(your_date_column)==w.value).show()
```

Check the image below for how the output looks like:

[image: Filter with Pyspark]

Answer (score 0):

As with all widgets, you can access the chosen value using `w.value`.

The ipywidgets tutorial can take you through some basic concepts: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Basics.html